# Change in the css class of any label

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3

How can i change the css class of any label or checkbox that have properties in model class and when i create a partial view i just want to change the css class of that particular label in mVC3.

Comment: Can you give a bit of an example from your View and your Model?

Comment: this should help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603016/extend-mvc3-razor-html-labelfor-to-add-css-class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603016/extend-mvc3-razor-html-labelfor-to-add-css-class)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
<label class="textlabel">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Property) :</label>
```

Defined css for that class.

```
.textlabel
{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #f8971d;
    float: right;
}
```